# What is URI and extraHeaderParameters?

Tags: android, multithreading, uri, handler, eventsource

I am using a library called EventSource and I implemented the thread, however, I am not sure what URI is or extraHeaderParameters? can someone please explain, also how would I handle this thread?

```
Thread eventThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            eventSource = new EventSource(mURI, new SSEHandler(), extraHeaderParameters);
            /* eventSource = new EventSource(UriProxy, UriApi, new SSEHandler(), extraHeaderParameters)*/
            eventSource.connect();
        } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.v("Error starting eventsource", "True");
        }
        eventThread.start();
    }

});
```

Comment: Is this the library you are using: https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android ?

Comment: Yes, that is the library I am using, I thought I posted the link sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mURI` is the URL of the SSE server you are connecting to.

`extraHeaderParameters` is an optional parameter for additional headers. You don't need to worry about giving any of the required SSE headers (see [source where it is used](https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android/blob/c1f6c670c789d8b6300e7bf8697691cca35781d3/eventsource_android/src/main/java/tylerjroach/com/eventsource_android/impl/netty/EventSourceChannelHandler.java#L70)), so basically it would be used for passing cookies, basic auth credentials, etc.